# How to make a random point and reference it to Transform?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm using Astar pathfinding project plugin and I have a `target` Transform, which is a point where the AI builds its path.
Currently I'm trying to implement a roaming state to my enemy. I've decided to create a random point and just shove it to `target`, but every solution I know or I've found regarding creating a random point is in either `Vector2` or `Vector3`.
How to create a random point and reference it to Transform variable?

I've tried [this solution](https://arongranberg.com/astar/documentation/dev_4_1_2_41647108/wander.php) from Astar project's tutorual (Method 1), but that didn't work for me. Here's almost the whole code just in case. *The problem is in a state machine in a state Roaming*.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Pathfinding;

public class EnemyAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Transform target; //that's what's all the fuss about
    private GameObject player;

    public float speed = 200f; 
    public float nextWaypointDistance = 3f; 
    public float radius;

    private float repeatPath = .5f; 

    enum State
    {
        Roaming,
        ChaseTarget,
        Attacking,
    }

    private State state;

    Path path; 
    int currentWaypoint; 
    bool reachedEndOfDestination = false;
    private Animator animator;
    private float horizontal;
    private float vertical;
    private Vector2 force;
    private GameObject gfx;


    private bool setAttackTimer;
    private float attackTimer;


    Seeker seeker;
    Rigidbody2D rb;

    private void Awake()
    {
        //state = State.Roaming;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        seeker = GetComponent<Seeker>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        gfx = GameObject.Find("CQBgfx");
        animator = gfx.GetComponent<Animator>();
        player = GameObject.Find("Player");
        target = player.transform;
        state = State.ChaseTarget;

        InvokeRepeating("UpdatePath", 0f, repeatPath);
    }

    void UpdatePath()
    {
        if (seeker.IsDone())
            seeker.StartPath(rb.position, target.position, OnPathComplete); //Here's the plugin forces me to use Transform
    }

    void OnPathComplete(Path p) 
    {
        if (!p.error)
        {
            path = p; 
            currentWaypoint = 1;
            reachedEndOfDestination = false;
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Movement();

        MovementAnimator();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        switch (state)
        {
            default:
            case State.Roaming:

                 Vector3 PickRandomPoint () {
                 var point = Random.insideUnitSphere * radius;
                 point.y = 0;
                 point += transform.position;
                 return point;
                 }

                target = PickRandomPoint(); //Error. Vector3 cannot be converted to Transform.
                break;

            case State.ChaseTarget:
                target = player.transform;
                break;

            case State.Attacking:
                break;
        }
    }

    void Movement()
    {
        if (path == null) 
            return;

        if (currentWaypoint >= path.vectorPath.Count) 
        {
            reachedEndOfDestination = true;
            rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;  
            force = Vector2.zero;       
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            reachedEndOfDestination = false;
        }

        if (!reachedEndOfDestination)
        {
            Vector2 direction = ((Vector2)path.vectorPath[currentWaypoint] - rb.position).normalized;
            force = direction * speed * Time.deltaTime; 

            rb.AddForce(force);
        }


        float distance = Vector2.Distance(rb.position, path.vectorPath[currentWaypoint]); 

        if (distance < nextWaypointDistance) 
            currentWaypoint++; 
    }

}
```

Comment: assign the random position vector to the transform of your object via setting transform.position

Comment: but that'll just make the object move there, no? I need to set a target for a pathfinding plugin so it builds a path to it

Comment: isnt it what you wanted? you said you wanted to "create a random point and reference it to Transform variable".

Comment: almost. i need to reference a random point to transform so the variable `target` can read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you absolutely *HAVE* to use a transform instance, (as I'm guessing you use `transform.position` to continuously follow a target) creating an empty GameObject and moving that to the target would work.

```cs
    private GameObject roamTarget; // <-- new roamTarget variable
    private Transform target; 
    private GameObject player;
    //...rest of variables

    void OnEnable()
    {
        // create roamTarget instance and reuse it for later
        roamTarget = new GameObject(gameObject.name + " Roam Target"); //just gives it a readable name
    }

    void OnDisable() 
    {
        // destroy our roamTarget on disable so we don't pollute our scene with unused gameobjects
        Destroy(roamTarget);
    }
```

and

```cs
    private void Update()
    {
        switch (state)
        {
            default:
            case State.Roaming:
                roamTarget.transform.position = PickRandomPoint();
                target = roamTarget;
                break;

            //...rest of switch cases
        }

        //...rest of Update()
   }
```

Just make sure to create one and move it around, instead of constantly instantiating and destroying targets,